# How to build docker image using Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

By using jenkins, I create an item of "Pipeline" type. And I set "Pipeline from SCM" to get `Jenkinsfile`. You can check my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kiwenlau/jenkins-test):

I want use Jenkins pipeline to build a docker image. Here is the Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
   sh "docker build -t 192.168.59.224:5000/ubuntu-test ."
}
```

The Dockerfile is also very simple:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y wget
```

When I run the project. I got following error:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Here is the full console output

```
Started by user kai
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ docker build -t 192.168.59.224:5000/ubuntu-test .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

I checked the workspace:

```
ls /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/


ls /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test@script/
Dockerfile
Jenkinsfile
```

There are nothing in **test** directory, but both Jenkinsfile and Dockerfile are in **test@script** directory.

It seems that Jenkins only get the Jenkins from the repository. When it execute the Jenkinsfile, it can not build the docker image without Dockerfile.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not instructing Jenkins to check out your repository. You do this by adding `checkout scm` before calling docker. Like this:

```
node {
  checkout scm
  sh "docker build -t 192.168.59.224:5000/ubuntu-test ."
}
```

The variable `scm` is set by Jenkins when you use "Pipeline from SCM" and points to the location where Jenkins got the Jenkinsfile from.

Comment: Okay, make sure that `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/Dockerfile`is checked out correctly. I would also suggest that you edit your question and add full log.

Comment: I've checked the workspace and add full log. Please check, THX.

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty clear that Jenkins doesn't check out the source in the workspace (not the `test@script`, that is just used by Jenkins for retrieving the Jenkinsfile). So is the log from my suggested pipeline script above (with `checkout scm`) or is it your initial? If you have an scm checkout you should see something like `Checking out Revision ...` in the logs.

Comment: Thank you! I made a mistake: I did not update the git repository correctly!