# Jenkinsfile docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running a jenkins instance on GCE inside a docker container and would like to execute a multibranch pipeline from this Jenkinsfile and Github. I'm using the [GCE jenkins](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-container-engine) tutorial for this. Here is my `Jenkinsfile`

```
node {
  def project = 'xxxxxx'
  def appName = 'gceme'
  def feSvcName = "${appName}-frontend"
  def imageTag = "eu.gcr.io/${project}/${appName}:${env.BRANCH_NAME}.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

  checkout scm

  sh("echo Build image")
  stage 'Build image'
  sh("docker build -t ${imageTag} .")

  sh("echo Run Go tests")
  stage 'Run Go tests'
  sh("docker run ${imageTag} go test")

  sh("echo Push image to registry")
  stage 'Push image to registry'
  sh("gcloud docker push ${imageTag}")

  sh("echo Deploy Application")
  stage "Deploy Application"
  switch (env.BRANCH_NAME) {
    // Roll out to canary environment
    case "canary":
        // Change deployed image in canary to the one we just built
        sh("sed -i.bak 's#eu.gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${imageTag}#' ./k8s/canary/*.yaml")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/services/")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/canary/")
        sh("echo http://`kubectl --namespace=production get service/${feSvcName} --output=json | jq -r '.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip'` > ${feSvcName}")
        break

    // Roll out to production
    case "master":
        // Change deployed image in canary to the one we just built
        sh("sed -i.bak 's#eu.gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${imageTag}#' ./k8s/production/*.yaml")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/services/")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/production/")
        sh("echo http://`kubectl --namespace=production get service/${feSvcName} --output=json | jq -r '.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip'` > ${feSvcName}")
        break

    // Roll out a dev environment
    default:
        // Create namespace if it doesn't exist
        sh("kubectl get ns ${env.BRANCH_NAME} || kubectl create ns ${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
        // Don't use public load balancing for development branches
        sh("sed -i.bak 's#LoadBalancer#ClusterIP#' ./k8s/services/frontend.yaml")
        sh("sed -i.bak 's#eu.gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${imageTag}#' ./k8s/dev/*.yaml")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=${env.BRANCH_NAME} apply -f k8s/services/")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=${env.BRANCH_NAME} apply -f k8s/dev/")
        echo 'To access your environment run `kubectl proxy`'
        echo "Then access your service via http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/${env.BRANCH_NAME}/services/${feSvcName}:80/"
  }
}
```

I always get an error `docker not found`:

```
[apiservice_master-GJCRJX6ZJPDVVSEUHIS6VBX7OYMFS5WKRVRKCSF4PSO76ZGZPKFQ] Running shell script
+ docker build -t eu.gcr.io/xxxxx/apiservice:master.1 .
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/apiservice_master-GJCRJX6ZJPDVVSEUHIS6VBX7OYMFS5WKRVRKCSF4PSO76ZGZPKFQ@tmp/durable-b4503ecc/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/apiservice_master-GJCRJX6ZJPDVVSEUHIS6VBX7OYMFS5WKRVRKCSF4PSO76ZGZPKFQ@tmp/durable-b4503ecc/script.sh: docker: not found
```

What do I have to change to make docker work inside jenkins?

Comment: Did you see [Container builder](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/overview) on GCP? It's very simple to use, just `gcloud container builds submit . -t ${imageTag}` instead of `docker build` and it will also be automatically pushed. However, this doesn't solve your tests (perhaps some small test GKE env?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like DiD (Docker in Docker), which this [recent issue](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-not-found-in-jenkins-pipeline/31683) points out as problematic.
See "[Using Docker-in-Docker for your CI or testing environment? Think twice.](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)"

That same issue recommends to run in privilege mode.
And make sure your docker container in which you are executing does have docker installed.

Comment: Thanks for the article. It helped to clear up a lot! You don't happen to have a tutorial or something where I can read up a complete solution that works?

Comment: @Tino Not exactly. I have other examples, but they might not run Jenkins itself in a Docker container: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42453967/6309, https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34276 (about using inside: https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#docker-workflow )

Comment: @Tino Also https://github.com/kranthiB/Build-Continuous-Integration-with-Jenkins-and-Dokcer mentioned DiD as well as DooD (Docker outside of Docker)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/50gtf9/how_to_build_docker_images_automatically_with/ does mention to map the docker socket into the jenkins container.

Answer (score 0):

You need the docker client installed in the Jenkins agent image used for that node, ie. [`cloudbees/java-with-docker-client`](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudbees/java-with-docker-client/)
And the docker socket mounted in the agent