# Build docker image in Jenkins (in docker container) pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-build

I use Jenkins from docker container. And I want to build docker image in Jenkins pipeline but docker is not exist in this container (where Jenkins).

Jenkins container deployed by Docker Compose, yml file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins:alpine
    ports:
      - 8085:8080
    volumes:
      - ./FOR_JENKINS:/var/jenkins_home
```

What we can do to build docker image in Jenkins pipeline?
Can we deploy some docker container with docker and use once for build docker image? or something else? How do you doing with they?

**Edit:**

Thanks @VonC, I checked your information, but... "permission denied"

Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins:alpine
    ports:
      - 8085:8080
    volumes:
      - ./FOR_JENKINS:/var/jenkins_home
#      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "Compiling..."
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt compile"
            }
        }
        /*stage('Unit Test') {
            steps {
                echo "Testing..."
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt coverage 'test-only * -- -F 4'"
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt coverageReport"
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt scalastyle || true"
            }
        }*/
        stage('DockerPublish') {
            steps {
                echo "Docker Stage ..."
                // Generate Jenkinsfile and prepare the artifact files.
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt docker:stage"

                echo "Docker Build-2 ..."
                // Run the Docker tool to build the image
                script {
                    docker.withTool('docker') {

                        echo "D1- ..."
                        //withDockerServer([credentialsId: "AWS-Jenkins-Build-Slave", uri: "tcp://192.168.0.29:2376"]) { 
                            echo "D2- ..."
                            sh "printenv" 
                            echo "D3- ..."
                            //sh "docker images" 
                            echo "D4- ..."
                            docker.build('my-app:latest', 'target/docker/stage').inside("--volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock")
                            echo "D5- ..."
                            //base.push("tmp-fromjenkins") 
                        //}

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[job1] Running shell script

+ docker build -t my-app:latest target/docker/stage

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.29/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=my-app%3Alatest&target=&ulimits=null: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

script returned exit code 1
```

**Edit:**
Last problem with "permission denied" fixed with:

```
>>sudo chmod 0777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

**Worked State:**

Call in host:

```
>>sudo chmod 0777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins:alpine
    ports:
      - 8085:8080
    volumes:
      - ./FOR_JENKINS:/var/jenkins_home
#      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "Compiling..."
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt compile"
            }
        }
        /*stage('Unit Test') {
            steps {
                echo "Testing..."
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt coverage 'test-only * -- -F 4'"
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt coverageReport"
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt scalastyle || true"
            }
        }*/
        stage('DockerPublish') {
            steps {
                echo "Docker Stage ..."
                // Generate Jenkinsfile and prepare the artifact files.
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt docker:stage"

                echo "Docker Build-2 ..."
                // Run the Docker tool to build the image
                script {
                    docker.withTool('docker') {

                        echo "D1- ..."
                        //withDockerServer([credentialsId: "AWS-Jenkins-Build-Slave", uri: "tcp://192.168.0.29:2376"]) { 
                            echo "D2- ..."
                            sh "printenv" 
                            echo "D3- ..."
                            //sh "docker images" 
                            echo "D4- ..."
                            docker.build('my-app:latest', 'target/docker/stage')
                            echo "D5- ..."
                            //base.push("tmp-fromjenkins") 
                        //}

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My resolve:**

I add some step in Jenkinsfile and get:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    //def app

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "Compiling..."
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt compile"
            }
        }

        stage('DockerPublish') {
            steps {
                echo "Docker Stage ..."
                // Generate Jenkinsfile and prepare the artifact files.
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt docker:stage"

                echo "Docker Build ..."
                // Run the Docker tool to build the image
                script {
                    docker.withTool('docker') {

                            echo "Environment:"
                            sh "printenv" 
                            app = docker.build('ivanbuh/myservice:latest', 'target/docker/stage')
                            echo "Push to Docker repository ..."
                         docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'docker-hub-credentials') {  
                                app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
                                app.push("latest")
                            }

                            echo "Complated ..."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
//https://boxboat.com/2017/05/30/jenkins-blue-ocean-pipeline/
//https://gist.github.com/bvis/68f3ab6946134f7379c80f1a9132057a
        stage ('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh "docker stack deploy myservice --compose-file docker-compose.yml"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you run docker in privilege mode though? (https://github.com/rancher/jenkins-master#running-docker-server-within-docker)

Comment: Property "privileged" is unsupported in Docker Compose file.

Comment: OK, then I suppose your chown is a good workaround for now. I have referenced it in the answer.

Comment: try to add 

'USER root'

to see if this solves the permission issue

Comment: @yorammi , where place to add 'USER root'?

Comment: I see that you don't have a Dockerfile :-(
There is should be placed

Comment: I will try see in docker step in jenkins pipeline for add root user

Comment: In jenkins pipeline you can add it if you'll have a docker.run as argument.
I don't know much about docker compose, but looking at the documentation I suggest to try adding this:

security_opt:

  - label:user:root

Comment: Problem is fixed, description on top "Result State". Thanks for everyone! You helped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look at "[Docker in Docker in Jenkins pipeline](http://nemerosa.ghost.io/2016/09/27/docker-in-docker-in-jenkins-pipeline/)". It includes the step:

> inside the Jenkinsfile, I need to connect my build container to the outer Docker instance. This is done by mounting the Docker socket itself:

```
docker.build('my-build-image').inside("--volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock") {  
   // The build here
}
```

You can see a similar approach in "[Building containers with Docker in Docker and Jenkins](https://renzedevries.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/building-containers-with-docker-in-docker-and-jenkins/)".

> In order to make the Docker from the host system available I need to make the API available to the Jenkins docker container. You can do this by mapping the docker socket that is available on the parent system.
>   I have created a small docker-compose file where I map both my volumes and the docker socket as following:

```
jenkins:
  container_name: jenkins
  image: myjenkins:latest
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - /Users/devuser/dev/docker/volumes/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
    - /var/run:/var/run:rw
```

> Please note the special mapping the ‘`/var/run`’ with `rw` privileges, this is needed to make sure the Jenkins container has access to the host systems `docker.sock`.

And, as I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960687/6309), you might need to run docker in privilege mode.
Or, as the OP reported:

```
sudo chmod 0777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I making next way which write on first post.